# Create a stored procedure that updates the personal info of an employee

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have done the following to create a stored procedure that updates the personal information of an employee in the EMPLOYEE table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_EMPLOYEE 
(
  THE_EMPLOYEEID IN NUMBER,
  NEW_LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
  NEW_FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
  NEW_TITLE IN VARCHAR2,
  NEW_REPORTSTO IN NUMBER,
  NEW_BIRTHDATE IN DATE,
  NEW_HIREDATE IN DATE,
  NEW_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
  NEW_CITY IN VARCHAR2,
  NEW_STATE IN VARCHAR2,
  NEW_COUNTRY VARCHAR2,
  NEW_POSTALCODE VARCHAR2,
  NEW_PHONE VARCHAR2,
  NEW_FAX VARCHAR2,
  NEW_EMAIL VARCHAR2
)
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMPLOYEE
  SET LASTNAME = 
        CASE NEW_LASTNAME 
        WHEN NULL THEN 
          LASTNAME
        ELSE NEW_LASTNAME
        END,
      FIRSTNAME =
        CASE NEW_FIRSTNAME 
        WHEN NULL THEN 
          FIRSTNAME
        ELSE NEW_FIRSTNAME
        END,
      TITLE = NEW_TITLE,
      REPORTSTO = NEW_REPORTSTO,
      BIRTHDATE = NEW_BIRTHDATE,
      HIREDATE = NEW_HIREDATE,
      ADDRESS = NEW_ADDRESS,
      CITY = NEW_CITY,
      STATE = NEW_STATE,
      COUNTRY = NEW_COUNTRY,
      POSTALCODE = NEW_POSTALCODE,
      PHONE = NEW_PHONE,
      FAX = NEW_FAX,
      EMAIL = NEW_EMAIL
    WHERE EMPLOYEEID = THE_EMPLOYEEID;
END UPDATE_EMPLOYEE;
```

EMPLOYEEID, LASTNAME, and FIRSTNAME are not nullable in the table EMPLOYEE.

I get this message:

```
Connecting to the database ChinookDB.
ORA-01407: cannot update ("CHINOOK"."EMPLOYEE"."LASTNAME") to NULL
ORA-06512: at "CHINOOK.UPDATE_EMPLOYEE", line 21
ORA-06512: at line 34
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database ChinookDB.
```

Can someone please inform me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would help to know how you are calling the procedure, too. For example: it seems you are connecting to a different database. If in that database, in the CHINOOK schema, you have a procedure by the same name, you may be using the "local" version, depending on how exactly you are calling it. Too many possible answers - knowing how you are using the procedure will help narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to ignore the `new_firstname` and `new_lastname` parameters if a `NULL` value is passed in.  If so, your `case` statements are wrong

```
CASE NEW_LASTNAME 
        WHEN NULL THEN 
          LASTNAME
        ELSE NEW_LASTNAME
        END,
```

will always return `new_lastname`.  No value, including `NULL` is ever equal to `NULL` so `when null` will always evaluate to `false`.  You could do something like

```
CASE WHEN new_lastname IS NULL
     THEN lastname
     ELSE new_lastname
 END
```

or more simply

```
COALESCE( new_lastname, lastname )
```

Of course, you have the same problem with the `new_firstname` expression.